# What does it mean to use BIC or AIC to clean residuals?

Tags: residuals, aic, bic

When I am studying the Augmented Dickey Fuller test I encountered with this phrase in my professor's textbook. It says exactly " In practice we use BIC or AIC to clean the residuals." It made no sense to me, I would appreciate if someone can make it more understandable.

Comment: It makes no sense to me either! I wonder what he or she had in mind.